# dataset for specialization of bachelor degrees

Tags: data-request, data.gov, education

I would like to know if there is any dataset that has the information about all education degrees and its specializations ? 
It need not be limited or it can be for USA.

Comment: can you use college scorecard? https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/ and https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collegescorecard

Comment: Does this [helpful](https://data.world/datasets/higher-education)